# What are "bound states" (in quantum physics)?

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-physics, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics

I read in Roger Newton's "Inverse Schrödinger Scattering in Three Dimensions" that the inverse problem in one dimension is not unique if there are *bound states*. Niether in his book nor on Wikipedia is there a good *mathematical* description of what a "bound state" is, thus I was wondering if someone could explain it to me (being a mathematician in analysis with almost no background in physics)?

Comment: This is a very good discussion on the topic: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92244/what-exactly-is-a-bound-state-and-why-does-it-have-negative-energy One way to think about it is that the solution space is discrete rather than continuous, for instance harmonic oscillator eigenstates versus plain waves. Another way to think about it is the set of states that decay rapidly at infinity (or are confined).

Comment: In addition to @CameronWilliams, confined would mean (in the one-dimensional case) that there exists an interval $[a,b]$ such that the probability of finding the particle there is non-vanishing. This happens when the wave-function decays rapidly enough so that it is integrable (and hence, normalizable).

Comment: @CameronWilliams You are describing when there are *no* bound states, if I understand correctly?

Comment: Square-integrable eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian? Simon puts "bound states" in quotes in ["On Positive Eigenvalues of One-Body
Schrodinger Operators"](http://www.math.caltech.edu/SimonPapers/5.pdf), which suggests it is not a precisely defined term. The possibility of positive eigenvalues contradicts the discussion linked by @CameronWilliams .

Comment: He says "point eigenvalues". I am sure he is referring to the [pure point spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_of_spectrum_(functional_analysis)#Decomposing_the_spectrum). That is what mathematical physicists mean by it. I think Newton's "class of admissible potentials" would be chosen to exclude the possibility of positive eigenvalues.